# How to resize a worksheet with the Google Client Library

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to resize a spreadsheet using the Google-provided library for API v4 (I have reasons not to use Gspread), but how can I do this?

I have tried a few methods and my current script is below; I am just looking for the request body I need to send. Also do I have to use batchUpdate or update?

Thank you in advance.

```
body = {
        "updateDimensionProperties": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": utils.spreadsheet_handler.spreadsheet_id,
                "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                "startIndex": 0,
                "endIndex": 1
            }
        }
    }

    utils.spreadsheet_handler.sheet.values().batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId=utils.spreadsheet_handler.spreadsheet_id,
        body=body).execute()  # Resizes the reservation spreadsheet
```

utils.spreadsheet_handler is a class that handles auth

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `resize a spreadsheet`? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about it.

Comment: i mean like if you had a 4x4 grid
and i said resize that to a 3x3

Comment: Thank you for your response. You want to reduce and/or increase the number of columns and rows using Sheets API with googleapis for python. Is my understanding correct? If it's so, can you provide your current script? Because from your question, I cannot understand about the current issue of your script. For example, I'm not sure whether your issue is resolved when only the request body is provided. If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: Ok I just added the code

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the script. I have a question. Is my understanding for your question correct? Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about this.

Comment: Yes. You are correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed 3 sample scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to increase and/or decrease the number of rows and columns of a worksheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Python.
- You have aleady been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, `UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest`, `AppendDimensionRequest` and `DeleteDimensionGroupRequest` for the batchUpdate method in Sheets API are used.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the number of rows and columns of worksheet becomes 5 and 5.

#### Sample script:

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId = "###"  # Please set the sheet ID.
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateSheetProperties": {
                "properties": {
                    "gridProperties": {
                        "rowCount": 5,
                        "columnCount": 5
                    },
                    "sheetId": sheetId
                },
                "fields": "gridProperties"
            }
        }
    ]
}
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, 10 rows and 10 columns are appended.

#### Sample script:

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId = "###"  # Please set the sheet ID.
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "appendDimension": {
                "sheetId": sheetId,
                "dimension": "ROWS",
                "length": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "appendDimension": {
                "sheetId": sheetId,
                "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                "length": 10
            }
        }
    ]
}
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()
```

### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, 10 rows and 10 columns are reduced. At the sample script, rows 1 to 10 and columns A to J are deleted.

#### Sample script:

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId = "###"  # Please set the sheet ID.
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "ROWS",
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 10
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 10
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()
```

### Note:

- Please select the sample script for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)
- [AppendDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appenddimensionrequest)
- [DeleteDimensionGroupRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensiongrouprequest)

Comment: Thank you. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @ギンヌメール美雲 Thank you for replying. In my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. But if in your environment, it didn't work. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the information you need is in the following links - from reading the GridProperties page it seems that you need to use rowCount and columnCount to resize your spreadsheet.

- [UpdateSpreadsheetProperties request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatespreadsheetpropertiesrequest)
- [GridProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#gridproperties)

About whether batchUpdate is required or not, the UpdateSpreadsheetProperties request allows for more than one property can be specified, so it should be possible to use that instead. batchUpdate is only required if you intend to update multiple properties that require different request types.

Comment: Can you please provide a example because the links don't really match and are a bit confusing.