# How to resize a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-api, python-3.6, google-sheets-api

I am trying to resize a google spreadsheet with the Google Sheets API with python, not GSpread, the one that is included in the docs. I follow this answer [How to resize a worksheet with the Google Client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791361/how-to-resize-a-worksheet-with-the-google-client-library) and came to this error:

```
C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\envs\japan-discord-bot-env\pythonw.exe C:/code/nexus-developments/japan-discord-bot/bot/main.py
Ignoring exception in command start:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\envs\japan-discord-bot-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\code\nexus-developments\japan-discord-bot\bot\cogs\manage_match.py", line 100, in start_command
    body=body).execute()  # Resizes the reservation spreadsheet
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\envs\japan-discord-bot-env\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\envs\japan-discord-bot-env\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1rss7ReSLSlFY4QiugUNDuWhciUVwdTGS8DVhvJ0CTPQ/values:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.'}]}]">

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\envs\japan-discord-bot-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\envs\japan-discord-bot-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\envs\japan-discord-bot-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1rss7ReSLSlFY4QiugUNDuWhciUVwdTGS8DVhvJ0CTPQ/values:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.'}]}]">
```

I used the first answer BTW.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your situation. Because in my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. In order to correctly replicate your issue, can you provide the whole script without your personal information? By this, I would like to confirm your issue. If you can do, please add it to your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Here is the full code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/denebodemu.py Discord.py is async if that has anything to do with it @Tanaike

Comment: If you want my utils class you can have it to look at

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. In my environment, I could confirm that your request body for `utils.spreadsheet_handler.sheet.values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=utils.spreadsheet_handler.spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()` worked. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your issue. I apologize for this. When you picked up only the script for resizing the worksheet and test it, did the script work?

Comment: Do you mean do it without the other code. I can try this. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. Can you test using the only the script for resizing the worksheet? When that worked, it can be thought that the issue was different part from the picked up script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214148/discussion-between-jpac14-and-tanaike).

Comment: Hi @Jpac14! I saw in a past [message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49430358#49430358) on the chat that you got an error from a failed execution. Could you please share the code so I can take a look?